# AWS Cloudwatch logs to ElasticSeacrh via Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to stream AWS cloudwatch logs to Amazon ES using Kinesis Firehose. However, I keep getting the below errors in the ES error log. Any idea?

The data could not be decoded as UTF-8 as in {"attemptsMade":0,"arrivalTimestamp":1494910856979,"errorCod‌​e":"InvalidEncodingE‌​xception","errorMess‌​age":"The data could not be decoded as UTF-8","attemptEndingTimestamp":1494911157268,"rawData":"H4s‌​IAAAAAAAAADWO0QqCMBi‌​FX2XsWiJBQ70LUW8sIYU‌​uQmLpnxvpJttMQnz3Ztr‌​lxzmcQj0RXNBWNMkErmk‌​SKoTfZSrmWQLoV1fBQlW‌​S9ZoLHrNUgFQ5u5a8XvY‌​HrBSfM6rWumdHQpDNjtu‌​M7vr333IPnOtZfbxG4pm‌​jTQ5tegEIK1YvxBlEgra‌​ZIPFFtlhgnyzOKmQQqFO‌​zwXM5fj/HcTewAAAA=",‌​"esDocumentId":null

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the prebuilt lambda to stream and using Firehose instead?

Comment: Hey, I wanted to stream to both s3 and ES and was using terraform to automate it. I didn't find a way to automate using terraform and using the "Stream to ES" method which is available on the console. If you have one, please do let me know.

Comment: If I had to use terraform (which I wouldn't because I already use Serverless), I would create lambda function from aws console from template, then copy the function code as [terraform lambda][1] and extend it with posting to s3, and then use [cloudwatch logs subscription filter][2] as source for the lambda you just created. Although I'm not familiar with Terraform, so this is mostly my guesswork.


  [1]: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html
  [2]: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.html

Comment: I can post the prev comment as answer if this makes sense for you. I see comments section messed up the links.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Adam.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably because Cloudwatch logs are compressed. You can use a Firehose transformation lambda blueprint and add code to uncompress the records.